# Maven won't exclude during copy-dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that uses Netty 4.0.29 and I have another dependency that pulls in netty 3.9.0. I put in an exclusion but it is still roping in 3.9.0 when I run copy-dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.31</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

If I run mvn dependency:tree with this exclusion in place, I see that it is indeed excluded:

```
[INFO] +- com.ning:async-http-client:jar:1.9.31:compile
```

But when I run mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies I see the jar 3.9.0 being copied along with the 4.0.29. According to the documentation and Google, this should not copy when there is an exclusion.

```
[INFO] Copying netty-3.9.0.Final.jar to /Users/udonom1/wk/141/coursecopy-api/target/dependency/netty-3.9.0.Final.jar
[INFO] Copying netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar to /Users/udonom1/wk/141/coursecopy-api/target/dependency/netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar
```

I tried excluding as suggested by the first answer below and that did not work.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>                               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>io.netty:netty:3.9.0.Final</excludeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I also added a dependency as further suggested:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.29.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use dependencyManagement to overwrite version for some dependency for all dependency tree.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are having the same issue. I used mvn -X and discovered that dependency:tree is omitting two other jars that are referencing netty. I added exclusions for those and I'm good to go. Spent a whole day on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing not library you have simple way to control versions of any dependency in your project - [`dependencyManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) block in root pom file, example:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.29.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Additional bonuses from this block - you can omit version and scope for dependency in concrete dependency (with same group id, artifact id and packaging).

PS another look to your dependencies make me ask you: are you sure that this dependency have single maven artifact id? `netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar` - seems that this artifact should have `netty-all` artifact id... If they have different artifact id's my recipe wouldn't help. In this case you should define build configuration for [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html), example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludeArtifactIds>io.netty:netty:3.9.0.Final</excludeArtifactIds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

or just use `-DexcludeArtifactIds` parameter in your maven call

Comment: how to exclude multiple artifacts

Comment: Separating artifactIds with ',', it works! Thank you.