# maven, copy non-excluded jars to folder

Tags: java, maven

I have a `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-no-one</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <dependency.scope>provided</dependency.scope>
        <postgresql.version>42.2.18</postgresql.version>
        <...>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <!-- resolves the parent pom from the repositories -->
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-spring-integration</artifactId>
            <version>${artemis-spring-integration.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_2.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
            <version>${artemis-server.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-json_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>${artemis-jms-client.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_2.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and in other sub-project I have a pom.xml file

```
<...>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy_jars</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<...>
```

And I want to copy all non-excluded dependencies from the first `pom.xml` to a folder `${project.build.directory}/modules`. The problem is that the end result is depended
jars + excluded jars. My question is how to copy all non-excluded jars to `${project.build.directory}/modules`. So, that the end result would be only jars from
dependencies minus excluded jars.

**Update no.1**

tried this [Maven won't exclude during copy-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771875/maven-wont-exclude-during-copy-dependencies), but no success.

Comment: Why are you copying the jars?

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom JRE by following instructions on this blog post https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/containerizing-apps-with-jlink

Comment: seems that this functionality is not available using maven